# Is list initialization of new struct{} using variables compiler specific?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

Using Visual Studio 2013 and C++ compiler to write yet another linked list and happened across this by trial and error. Is this specific to Visual C++ or part of the standard?

I really like this syntax. It's super clean. If you've written a linked list lib before you know you can chase pointers around until your brain is tied in knots. This syntax though is crystal clear.

Lots of this stuff with static initializer values, but using function args as initializers? Haven't seen that yet.

It would be comforting to know if the **GCC C/C++ compiler** produces the expected result. Anyone?

```
typedef struct link_in_list {
    struct link_in_list *next;
    int32_t key;
    int32_t value;
}   LINK, *pLINK;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
pLINK prepend_list(pLINK head, int32_t key, int32_t value)
{
    if (NULL == head)   {
        // initialize with a constant, variable, and expression
        return new LINK{ NULL, key, (key * key) };
    }   else    {
        // initialize with stack variables
        return new LINK{ head, key, value };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly legal. Although that conditional is perfectly pointless.

Comment: Perfectly pointless.

Comment: @T.C.  I changed the code to make the NULL case a more interesting initialization, destroying its perfect pointlessness.

Answer (score 6):

This is called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and was introduced in C++11. It's different from direct initialization in a bunch of ways that I would like to point out:

```
int x{3.5}; // illegal - narrowing
int x(3.5); // fine, x is 3, but does this make sense?

T fun(); // this is a function returning a T
T fun{}; // this is a default constructed object
         // of type T

 std::vector<int> v(10, 20); // 10 elems: 20, 20, 20, ..., 20
 std::vector<int> v{10, 20}; // 2 elems: 10, 20
```

But outside of those cases, it's pretty similar to direct initialization. So no, it's not compiler specific - as long as the compiler in question supports the new language standard.

One addition in functionality is that if `T` is an "aggregate" (that is, an array, or a class type that has no private/protected members, no user-provided constructors, no base classes, no virtual methods), then list initialization is equivalent to aggregate initialization.

That is:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
};

int i = 1;
char c = 'b';
double d = 42.;

Foo f{i, c, d};
Foo g = {i, c, d};
```

Those lines are equivalent.

Comment: Nice succinct summary!

Comment: How does this address my question? I don't see any variables used as initializers. My struct{} is POD, not a vector.

Comment: Also, given functions `f` and `g`, `T foo(f(), g());` can evaluate either call first; `T foo{f(), g()};` will evaluate `f()` before `g()`. Similarly, `T foo(i++, i++);` is UB, `T foo{i++, i++};` isn't.

Comment: @RocketRoy why does the variables part matter? I added an explanation of list initialization used as aggregate initialization.

Comment: Are you declaring here and now that it does NOT matter? That would address my question. I've read 20 odd discussions on list initialization, including the one you linked. Not a single variable to be found on those initialization lists, thus my question, is it compiler specific or part of the standard.

Comment: @RocketRoy Are you really asking "Can you initialize a variable with a variable?" Of course. That has always been true. What kind of useless language would not let you do that?

Comment: @RocketRoy Examples tend to use literals since you know what type `1`, `'b'`, and `42.` are without me having to say it. But I just added variables for you.

Comment: Excellent. Now hopefully others who waste time reading the dry, useless tomes, online or otherwise, on list initialization without a variable to be found anywhere, will know they can safely use this syntax as well. Surprising how something so "obvious" escaped dozens of tech writers. Nice of you to get around to actually answering the question asked, even if you felt it necessary to imply I'm the idiot first. Gotta love StackOverflow.

Comment: The distinction is between constants the compiler knows at compile time, and the assignment of variables known only at run-time. It's an important distinction. Classic C 89 for example does not support declaring an array of a variable size because the compiler needs to know the required stack size at compile time, which is impossible with a run-time sized array[x]. Using list initialization with variables means there is now a new, succinct alternative to using multiple assignment operators, usually comprising multiple lines of code, after calling new to allocate a struct{}.